# SDL rendering too slow

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm a beginner in both C++ and SDL, and I'm slowly writing a small game following some tutorials to learn some concepts.

I'm having a problem, though: My rendering seems to be *really* slow.
I've used PerformanceCounters to calculate my loops with and without my rendering function. Without it, I get 0~2ish milliseconds per frame; when I add the rendering, it goes up to 65ish ms per frame.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my rendering function?

```
SDL_Texture *texture;

...

// gets called by the main loop
void render(int x_offset, int y_offset)
{
  if (texture)
  {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
  }

  texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
      SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
      SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
      texture_w,
      texture_h);

  if (SDL_LockTexture(texture, NULL, &pixel_memory, &pitch) < 0) {
    printf("Oops! %s\n", SDL_GetError());
  }

  Uint32 *pixel;
  Uint8 *row = (Uint8 *) pixel_memory;

  for (int j = 0; j < texture_h; ++j) {
    pixel = (Uint32 *)((Uint8 *) pixel_memory + j * pitch);
    for (int i = 0; i < texture_w; ++i) {

      Uint8 alpha = 255;
      Uint8 red = 172;
      Uint8 green = 0;
      Uint8 blue = 255;

     *pixel++ = ((alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue));

    }
  }
  SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your compilation flags are set to -O0  for debugging?

Comment: Why create and destroy the texture each time?  Would it not be better to re-use it?

Comment: I'm compiling with **c++ ../linux_handmade.cpp -o handmadehero -g `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`**, so, yes, the -g is there. I tried removing the -g and also removed the SDL_DestroyTexture,  but didn't better numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The SDL2 is based on hardware rendering. Acessing textures, even with the streaming flag won't be fast since you play ping pong with the GPU.

Instead of creating and destroying a texture each frame, you should consider simply cleaning it before redrawing.

Another option would be to use a surface. You do your stuff with the surface and then draw it as a texture. I'm not sure that the gain would be huge but I think it will still be better than destroying, creating, locking and unlocking a texture each frame.

Looking at your code, I understand it is but a test, though you could try to render to a texture with SDL primitives.

Lastly, keep in mind during your tests that your driver might force the vertical sync, which could lead to fake bad performance.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely slow because you're destroying and creating the texture every single frame, locking textures/uploading pixel data isn't super fast, but I doubt it's the bottleneck here. I strongly recommend allocating the texture once before entering your main loop and re-using it during rendering, then destroying it before your program exits.

Comment: This is what I was doing before. But I ran into a strange bug: **only** when I added SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER to the Init function, increasing the Height of the window would make writing into the texture's pixels segfault - as if it wasn't expanding correctly, I'm not sure. That changed when I started re-allocating the texture, as if it was re-sizing it properly. I'm not sure what was wrong, but the commit is here, in case you or anyone want to see it =]
https://github.com/thyagobr/handmadehero/commit/395969ebab77edd7f4409219e4d9f9ba0b59af2f

Comment: Oh I see, yes if you're re-sizing the window and this texture is supposed to cover the whole screen you will need to re-create it to match the new size. However, you should only re-create it when the window size changes, not every frame. To do this you can watch for an [SDL_WindowEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent?highlight=%28\bCategoryStruct\b%29|%28CategoryEvents%29) telling you that the window resized, then get the new size and re-create the texture only as needed. It looks like you already handle this event, so just re-allocate the texture there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Probably nothing. Locking textures for direct pixel access is slow. Chances are, you can do a lot of additional stuff in the render function and not see any further decrease in speed.

If you want faster rendering, you need higher-level functions.

Comment: I think that's it.  In this case it looks like you're looping through a new texture setting it to purple pixel by pixel; I bet you'd get a massive speedup if you did a scaled blit of a pre-existing purple texture onto your new texture.  (I don't remember off the top of my head how exactly you do that in SDL.)  At the least, don't do this every iteration of your render loop... do it once at startup and save the texture.

Comment: I figured the inner loop was just an example, not the actual code in the render loop.

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this as answer and move on, but one think is really bugging me: this is a "translation" of a code done in windows (Handmade Hero series, by Casey Muratori). His pixel-by-pixel drawing on windows doesn't seem to affect the loop so much. (Here's the entire 'class', in case anyone's interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAcUIEoy2Yk)